# What's the "Caly" in "Calydon"?

Tags: greek, etymology

In Greek mythology, there was a terrifying monster known as the Calydonian Boar.  It was called the "Calydonian Boar" because it was a monstrous pig that terrorized the town called "Calydon".

Now, in the Greek language, "don" means "tooth", so, as the title says, what does the "caly" in "Calydon" mean?

Comment: The Greek for tooth is not *don*, but *odous* (stem *odont-*); the name of the town is unrelated to this word, and is probably to be segmented *Calyd-ōn*, since *-ōn* is a common derivational ending.

Comment: Although in Modern Greek they do say ˈðɔndi or ˈðɔdi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The origin of the town's name is ultimately unclear, and is missing from many dictionaries. The -don is probably a coincidence, though, and we can probably assume it's Pre-Greek or some borrowing from nearby tribes.

Similar words that might give a clue (καλύβη "kalubē", καλυδίλα "kaludila") are classified as Pre-Greek by Beekes (p. 628 for a smattering of words).

Comment: I don't read actual Greek, so could you Romanize the "similar words" for me?

Comment: @JohnWDailey _Calybë_ and _calydila_

Comment: @Draconis  I found something on "Calybe" but nothing on "calydila".

Comment: @JohnWDailey Use Beekes, *Etymological Dictionary of Greek*.

Comment: Town named after mythological [hero](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Apollod.+1.7.7&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0022:book=1:chapter=7&highlight=Calydon).

Comment: Correction: town *said* to be named after said Calydon.  Beekes'  likely Pre-Greek καλυδίλα=bridge might relate to the town's mountain location?

Comment: @CosmasZachos That seems to be the idea.